# How to Find Greater Than of an Alphanumeric String

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that look like below

```
SalesOrderNo
------------
1
2
D1
D2
D11
D12
D16
D20
D21
```

I want to search and find  all the sales order numbers that are grater than D16
this is what I have tried

```
Select SalesOrderNo From tbl_Sales Where SalesOrderNo > 'D16' and  SalesOrderNo LIKE 'D%'
```

and This is What I Get

```
D2
D20
D21
```

But The Desired Out Put is

```
D20
D21
```

Comment: Define "greater than."  What is the numeric value of `D16`?  Is it possible that `A232` could have the same value?

Comment: the output is correct since if we look at the second character of `D16`, the value is 1, and 1 is lesser than 2 taking `D2` as a valid result/

Comment: The problem is that there is no such thing as an alphanumeric number. You can either compare strings or compare numbers, but getting a string to behave like a number has the potential to cause a massive performance hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the integer in right part using `RIGHT` function.

**Query**

```
select SalesOrderNo from tbl_sales
where SalesOrderNo LIKE 'D%'
and cast(right(SalesOrderNo, len(SalesOrderNo) - 1) as int) > 16;
```

### [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/500269/how-to-find-greater-than-of-an-alphanumeric-number)

Comment: Thanks Man Its Solved The Problem,

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

Assuming  after D there is numbers only.

```
     Select SalesOrderNo From tbl_Sales 
        Where to_number(replace(SalesOrderNo,'D','')) > 16 
        and  SalesOrderNo LIKE 'D%'
```

Comment: its Gives an error 'to_number' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: thats right on sql server u need to use Cast like Ullas use. cast(right(SalesOrderNo, len(SalesOrderNo) - 1) as int). Sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to represents the D and any other letter with a digit.

```
select * from 
@tbl_Sales 


where 
    order by 
    case
    when SalesOrderNo like 'D%' then cast(replace(SalesOrderNo,'D','') as int) + 100000
    else cast(SalesOrderNo as int) 
    END > 100016--D16

order by 
case
when SalesOrderNo like 'D%' then cast(replace(SalesOrderNo,'D','') as int) + 100000
else cast(SalesOrderNo as int) 
END
```

Although if u have a big table,  i recommend you to create another column and fill it with this integer values for performance purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query,

```
DECLARE @InputColumn AS VARCHAR(20)
SET @InputColumn = 'D16'
SELECT  SalesOrder
FROM    dbo.Section
WHERE   CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(SalesOrder, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', SalesOrder),
                               LEN(SalesOrder))) > CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@InputColumn,
                                                              PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',
                                                              @InputColumn),
                                                              LEN(@InputColumn)))
ORDER BY LEFT(SalesOrder, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', SalesOrder) - 1) ,
        CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(SalesOrder, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', SalesOrder),
                               LEN(SalesOrder)))
```